# On ruler-only construction

Tags: calculus, geometry

There is a ruler with two different labels on it (1 inch, for example). The task is to find out if it is possible to construct a perpendicular to the given line.

I have found a way to construct a rectangle, but the given line is not its side, but a diagonal.

Comment: How many edges does your ruler have? (it gets easy if it has two parallel edges)

Comment: @Henry No, unfortunately, it is a line

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible:

[image]

Pick any point on the given line, and call it point $A$. Make a unit segment with one endpoint at $A$, and the other endpoint at a random point not on the line, call the endpoint $B$. Extend segment $AB$ one unit, and call the new endpoint $D$. Point $B$ should be in between $A$ and $D$. Now, find a point on the given line, $C\neq A$, such that $AB=CB$ (you can do this by putting one ruler mark on point B and swinging the ruler around until the other ruler mark hits the line). Draw line $CD$.

Comment: Is this a 30-60-90 right triangle? Is that why you didn't provide a proof or explanation of why angle $C$ was a right angle?

Comment: It's not any particular triangle; it's merely right.  angle C is a right angle because both ABC and BCD are isosceles triangles; write BCD in terms of CBD in terms of ABC in terms of ACB to see why.

Comment: @scott To see why ACD is a right angle, draw a circle around B with radius of one unit. You'll see that the angle ACD must be right since it inscribes half of the circle.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to swing ruler around a given point until the mark intersects with something.

Can we solve it without it?